# Can a path be used intsead of a boolean in the syntax of 'if' in python

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, path

I have come across code in image processing where the following statement is used:

```
#args is a dictionary     
if not args.get("video",False)
```

The get() method returns:

the value for the specified key if key is in dictionary.

None if the key is not found and value is not specified.

value if the key is not found and value is specified.

But the dictionary has a key "video" which is the path to a video file, and it is used later in this way:

```
  if args.get("video")
```

So args.get("video") would give the path to a file. My question is, is this valid syntax for 'if' or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's valid.

A `str` will return `True` as long as it's not `""`.

As per the documentation - [Truth Value Testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing):

> Any object can be tested for truth value, for use in an if or while condition or as operand of the Boolean operations below.
>
> By default, an object is considered true unless its class defines either a __bool__() method that returns `False` or a __len__() method that returns zero, when called with the object. Here are most of the built-in objects considered false:
>
> • constants defined to be false: `None` and `False`.
>
> • zero of any numeric type: `0`, `0.0`, `0j`, `Decimal(0)`, `Fraction(0, 1)`
>
> • empty sequences and collections: `''`, `()`, `[]`, `{}`, `set()`, `range(0)`

Answer (score 3):

Classes in python can establish a `__bool__(self)` [method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__). If the function is defined, then when the member is accessed via `if`, the code in `__bool__` runs and decides whether to return `True` or `False`. So yes, the line is valid python. It will call `bool()` on whatever `args.get()` returns, which will run the `__bool__()` method of the parent class.

If `args.get()` returns a string, e.g. the location of some file, it will evaluate as `True`. All python strings will evaluate to `True` if they are not empty.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is a valid statement.But if this **args.get("video")** return **None** the it will not execute if block